# Removing 'count' from 'comments' Graph API connection

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

recently read [fb developer roadmap](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/) and the section "Removing 'count' from 'comments' Graph API connection".Does it mean that if i call graph api like https://graph.facebook.com/page_id/feed then in data the "count" field will be deprecated located under "comments" field ? or in some other calls ? please answer asap i did not get help anywhere.

Answer (score 6):

If I understand you correctly, and you want the comments counts for each feed in page in one call, try this syntax :

```
pageID/posts?fields=comments.limit(2).summary(true).filter(toplevel)
```

Answer (score 3):

It's exactly as it states it in the roadmap

> Removing 'count' from 'comments' Graph API connection
>   We are removing the undocumented 'count' field on the 'comments' connection in the Graph API. Please request '{id}/comments?summary=true' explicitly if you would like the summary field which contains the count (now called 'total_count')

So you would need to add summary=true to your call and then use the total_count field

Comment: i used "https://graph.facebook.com/page_id/feed?summary=true" but i don't see total_count field in graph api explorer!.recall that i am calling this way - "https://graph.facebook.com/page_id/feed" not by that - "https://graph.facebook.com/post_id/comments?summary=true".

Comment: When I make that call using the graph api explorer, for each post in the feed connection I still see a field with a count option

Comment: So its not resolved yet.will i take into account the after july 12 i will not see "count" field when i call graph.facebook.com/page id/feed ?

Answer (score 1):

Using Facebook Graph API Explorer, I've got different results depends which application i'm using with the Explorer.

By default with the application "Graph API Explorer", I see the summary section in my results but if I select my app, summary section disappears in results.

I use the same permissions and requests as the app "Graph API Explorer".

Any idea ?