# default comment count in facebook graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I have been using facebook's graph api. Now I got to know that there will not be a count field in "comment" object in the returned JSON. Now we have to make an extra effort for finding the total comments on the post which I do not want if I know the default number of comments put by the API in the JSON.

If I have the default number then I get to know whether I have to make a separate call for finding the total number of comments.

So, could anyone tell me the default comment count value?

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to get count of comments back.

It's example from developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

SocialMediaClubMoscow?fields=feed.fields(comments.limit(1).filter(toplevel),message,likes,shares,from)

```
      }, 
      "summary": {
        "order": "chronological", 
        "total_count": 12
      }
```

total_count - is count of all comments

Related topic:
[Removing 'count' from 'comments' Graph API connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16221746/removing-count-from-comments-graph-api-connection)